# NodeJS 'toUpperCase' of undefined (generated from typescript)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Why this works when I launch from nodejs:

```
var a = function (name) {
        return "Hello, " + name.toUpperCase();
    };
var result = a("bob");

console.log(result)
```

But this:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(msg) {
        this.msg = " ";
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    A.prototype.hello = function (name) {
        return "Hello, " + name.toUpperCase();
    };
    A.prototype.helloToBob = function (fn) {
        return fn.apply("Bob");
    };
    return A;
})();
var test = new A("some message");
var msg = test.hello("Bob1");
var msg2 = test.helloToBob(test.hello);
console.log(msg);
```

fails with:

> ```
>     return "Hello, " + name.toUpperCase();
>                             ^ TypeError: Cannot call method 'toUpperCase' of undefined
> ```

?

That JS code generated/compiled from TypeScript code.(compiled with no errors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in this line of code.

```
 return fn.apply("Bob");
```

The are a couple issues here.

1. The first argument to `.apply(obj, arrayOfArguments)` needs to be the object that you want the `this` pointer set to during the method call.
2. The second argument for `.apply()` is an array of arguments, not a single argument.

Here's one possible solution where you use `this` as the object and switch to `fn.call()` because `fn.apply()` takes an array of arguments, but you just have a single argument.

Change this:

```
 return fn.apply("Bob");
```

to this:

```
return fn.call(this, "Bob");
```

And, all the code together:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(msg) {
        this.msg = " ";
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    A.prototype.hello = function (name) {
        return "Hello, " + name.toUpperCase();
    };
    A.prototype.helloToBob = function (fn) {
        return fn.call(this, "Bob");
    };
    return A;
})();
var test = new A("some message");
var msg = test.hello("Bob1");
var msg2 = test.helloToBob(test.hello);
console.log(msg);
```

---

FYI, there are other solutions.  You could also do this:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(msg) {
        this.msg = " ";
        this.msg = msg;
    }
    A.prototype.hello = function (name) {
        return "Hello, " + name.toUpperCase();
    };
    A.prototype.helloToBob = function (fn) {
        return fn("Bob");
    };
    return A;
})();
var test = new A("some message");
var msg = test.hello("Bob1");
var msg2 = test.helloToBob(test.hello.bind(test));
console.log(msg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the first argument you should pass to apply() is the context object, it is NOT the first argument of the function itself. Do check the docs.

Since helloToBob() is a class method of A, I assume, you intend to call fn in the context of the current object, is this what you are after:

```
A.prototype.helloToBob = function (fn) {
    return fn.apply(this, ["Bob"]);
};

// or, since you have a single static argument, use function.call instead:

A.prototype.helloToBob = function (fn) {
    return fn.call(this, "Bob");
};
```

Comment: `.apply()` takes an array of arguments, not a single argument.

Comment: Oops, you're right! I was so focused on the context I forgot the signature. Thanks for the correction @jfriend00, I've edited my answer.